# Moving a Mercurial repository between OS's

Tags: windows, ubuntu, file-transfer, mercurial

I have been working with a local Mercurial repository on my Ubuntu PC for my personal documents. I am planning on using Windows more frequently, so I would like to move the repository over to my Windows PC.

Is it safe to simply copy the entire folder over between systems? Or must I do something else, such as clone?

Note: the Ubuntu PC is not connected to the Windows PC. I am hoping to move the repository via USB thumb drive.

Comment: Clone will be more natural way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested this, and copying from my Ubuntu server to my Windows 7 laptop worked fine. TortoiseHg recognised everything and had all the history to hand.

I copied via SFTP, though, so line endings were converted into the Windows version. I would hope that Mercurial on Windows would do the right thing, but if you want to be sure, you can run [unix2dos](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/) on the Windows PC after the copy. Running it beforehand on the Ubuntu side will leave your repository with the wrong line endings, though you could fix that...

Comment: Wonderful. Good to know.